# Is it possible to transform `T` to `ref T`?

Tags: d

```
alias refT(T) = ref T;
void test1(refT!int v){
    v = 42;
}

void test2(ref int v){
    v = 42;
}

void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    int i = 5;
    test1(i);
    writeln(i); // 5
    test2(i);
    writeln(i); // 42
}
```

`test1` doesn't mutate `i` which tells me that it is not capturing `i` as a reference. Is `ref` a special qualifier that can not be used in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ref` is not a qualifier](https://dlang.org/spec/declaration.html#typequal_vs_storageclass):

> Although some keywords can be used both as a type qualifier and a storage class, there are some storage classes that cannot be used to construct new types. One example is ref.